# Interactive plot with ipywidgets while other work is performed

Tags: python, ipython, interactive, ipywidgets

When I use plotly and then some further code (e.g. time.sleep(5)), zooming in etc. works during the time.sleep(5). (I am using jupyter lab). However, when using interactive from ipywidgets, the plot is not updated during time.sleep(5).

Here is some basic code showing the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive
from IPython.display import display

def update_plot(x):
    plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,x,2])
    plt.show()
y = interactive(update_plot, x = widgets.FloatSlider(min = -1, max = 3, value = 0.1))
display(y)
time.sleep(5)
```

The use case is e.g. to have some interactive plotting during epochs of training neural network, so there would be a for loop around this, with clear_output() at the beginning of each loop. Would really like to have the interactive plotting to check on the progress without completely spamming the output window.

I have tried creating an extra thread (with threading) for the time.sleep(5) (Then the program just ends as the main thread ends, i.e. the heavy work is not performed). Also tried creating an extra thread for the interactive plot, but it still doesnt work. The interactive plot only updates after the time.sleep(5) is done.

Any help/suggestions would be really appreciated!